# Why is PDF only rendering correctly with Adobe Acrobat?

Tags: pdf

My self made pdfs only render correctly if opened with Adobe Acrobat.

The file from code below renders in Adobe Acrobat exactly as I intended.

With Revu, only the text renders correctly (lines do not show at all).
With other viewers there are different issues still.

Can anyone see the problem in this code?

```
%PDF-1.7

1 0 obj
    <<
        /Title (Test)
        /Author ()
        /Creator ()
        /Producer ()
        /CreationDate (D:20231130091537+01'00')
    >>
endobj

2 0 obj
    <<
        /Type /Catalog
        /Pages 3 0 R
        /PageLayout /OneColumn
        /PageMode /UseNone
        /Lang (en)
        /ViewerPreferences
            <<
                /HideToolbar false
                /DisplayDocTitle true
                /PrintScaling /None
                /HideWindowUI false
            >>
    >>
endobj

5 0 obj
    <<
        /Type /Font 
        /Subtype /TrueType
        /Name /Fnt1
        /BaseFont /TimesNewRoman
        /Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding
    >>
endobj

6 0 obj
    <<
        /Type /Font 
        /Subtype /TrueType
        /Name /Fnt2
        /BaseFont /Helvetica
        /Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding
    >>
endobj

7 0 obj
    <<
        /Type /Page
        /Parent 3 0 R
        /Contents 8 0 R
        /MediaBox [0 0 612 792]
        /CropBox [0 0 612 792]
        /Resources
            <<
                /ExtGState
                    <<
                        /GS  <</ca 1    /CA 1    >>
                        /GS0 <</ca 0    /CA 0    >>
                        /GS1 <</ca 0.25 /CA 0.25 >>
                        /GS2 <</ca 0.5  /CA 0.5  >>
                        /GS3 <</ca 0.75 /CA 0.75 >>
                        /GS4 <</ca 1    /CA 1    >>
                    >>
                /Font
                    <<
                        /Fnt1 5 0 R 
                        /Fnt2 6 0 R 
                    >>
            >>
    >>
endobj

8 0 obj
    << /Length 9 0 R >>
stream
    
    BT
        /Fnt1 23.04 Tf
        284.239 738.72 Td
        (R) Tj
    ET
 
    BT
        /Fnt1 8.64 Tf
        303.84 36 Td
        (Page 1) Tj
    ET

    %----------------------------------------------
    q
    0 G
    0 g
    0 w
    W
    n
    54.72 684.72 501.93 71.28 re
    n
    1 0 0 1 -2921.22 583.74 cm
    0.72 0 0 0.72 0 0  cm
    1 0 0 -1 0 0  cm
    1 0 0 1 0 -380.1875 cm
    0 G
    0.5 w
    0 G
    0 173.938 m
    60060 173.938 l
    S
    0 G
    0 182.188 m
    60060 182.188 l
    S
    0 G
    0 190.438 m
    60060 190.438 l
    S
    0 G
    0 198.688 m
    60060 198.688 l
    S
    0 G
    0 206.938 m
    60060 206.938 l
    S
    0 G
    f
    Q
    q
    0 G
    0 g
    0 w
    W
    n
    54.72 684.72 501.93 71.28 re
    n
    1 0 0 1 -2921.22 583.74 cm
    0.72 0 0 0.72 0 0  cm
    1 0 0 -1 0 0  cm
    1 0 0 1 0 -380.1875 cm
    0 w
    0 G
    Q
    q
    0 G
    0 g
    0 w
    W
    n
    54.72 684.72 501.93 71.28 re
    n
    1 0 0 1 -2921.22 583.74 cm
    0.72 0 0 0.72 0 0  cm
    1 0 0 -1 0 0  cm
    1 0 0 1 0 -380.1875 cm
    f
    Q
    q
    0 G
    0 g
    0 w
    W
    n
    54.72 684.72 501.93 71.28 re
    n
    1 0 0 1 -2921.22 583.74 cm
    0.72 0 0 0.72 0 0  cm
    0 w
    0 G
    f
    Q
    %----------------------------------------------

endstream
endobj

9 0 obj
    12357
endobj

10 0 obj
    <<
        /Type /Page
        /Parent 3 0 R
        /Contents 11 0 R
        /MediaBox [0 0 612 792]
        /CropBox [0 0 612 792]
        /Resources
            <<
                /ExtGState
                    <<
                        /GS  <</ca 1    /CA 1    >>
                        /GS0 <</ca 0    /CA 0    >>
                        /GS1 <</ca 0.25 /CA 0.25 >>
                        /GS2 <</ca 0.5  /CA 0.5  >>
                        /GS3 <</ca 0.75 /CA 0.75 >>
                        /GS4 <</ca 1    /CA 1    >>
                    >>
                /Font
                    <<
                        /Fnt1 5 0 R 
                        /Fnt2 6 0 R 
                    >>
            >>
    >>
endobj

11 0 obj
    << /Length 12 0 R >>
stream
    
    BT
        /Fnt2 23.04 Tf
        284.239 738.72 Td
        (R) Tj
    ET

    BT
        /Fnt2 8.64 Tf
        303.84 36 Td
        (Page 2) Tj
    ET

    %----------------------------------------------
    q
    0 G
    0 g
    0 w
    W
    n
    54.72 684.72 501.93 71.28 re
    n
    1 0 0 1 -2921.22 583.74 cm
    0.72 0 0 0.72 0 0  cm
    1 0 0 -1 0 0  cm
    1 0 0 1 0 -380.1875 cm
    0 G
    0.5 w
    0 G
    0 173.938 m
    60060 173.938 l
    S
    0 G
    0 182.188 m
    60060 182.188 l
    S
    0 G
    0 190.438 m
    60060 190.438 l
    S
    0 G
    0 198.688 m
    60060 198.688 l
    S
    0 G
    0 206.938 m
    60060 206.938 l
    S
    0 G
    f
    Q
    q
    0 G
    0 g
    0 w
    W
    n
    54.72 684.72 501.93 71.28 re
    n
    1 0 0 1 -2921.22 583.74 cm
    0.72 0 0 0.72 0 0  cm
    1 0 0 -1 0 0  cm
    1 0 0 1 0 -380.1875 cm
    0 w
    0 G
    Q
    q
    0 G
    0 g
    0 w
    W
    n
    54.72 684.72 501.93 71.28 re
    n
    1 0 0 1 -2921.22 583.74 cm
    0.72 0 0 0.72 0 0  cm
    1 0 0 -1 0 0  cm
    1 0 0 1 0 -380.1875 cm
    f
    Q
    q
    0 G
    0 g
    0 w
    W
    n
    54.72 684.72 501.93 71.28 re
    n
    1 0 0 1 -2921.22 583.74 cm
    0.72 0 0 0.72 0 0  cm
    0 w
    0 G
    f
    Q
    %----------------------------------------------

endstream
endobj

12 0 obj
    9177
endobj

4 0 obj
    <<
        /Font
            <<
                /Fnt1 5 0 R 
                /Fnt2 6 0 R 
            >>
        /ProcSet [/PDF /Text ]
    >>
endobj

3 0 obj
    <<
        /Type /Pages
        /Count 2
        /MediaBox [0 0 612 792]
        /CropBox [0 0 612 792]
        /Rotate 0
        /Kids [7 0 R 10 0 R  ]
        /Resources 4 0 R
    >>
endobj

xref
0 13
0000000000 65535 f
0000000010 00000 n
0000000231 00000 n
0000051000 00000 n
0000052000 00000 n
0000055189 00000 n
0000000601 00000 n
0000029578 00000 n
0000031043 00000 n
0000043465 00000 n
0000043492 00000 n
0000044957 00000 n
0000054199 00000 n

trailer
<<
    /Size 13
    /Info 1 0 R
    /Root 2 0 R
>>
startxref
55407
%%EOF
```

Revised code

```
%PDF-1.7

1 0 obj
    <<
        /Title (Test)
        /Author ()
        /Creator ()
        /Producer ()
        /CreationDate (D:20231130091537+01'00')
    >>
endobj

2 0 obj
    <<
        /Type /Catalog
        /Pages 3 0 R
        /PageLayout /OneColumn
        /PageMode /UseNone
        /Lang (en)
        /ViewerPreferences
            <<
                /HideToolbar false
                /DisplayDocTitle true
                /PrintScaling /None
                /HideWindowUI false
            >>
    >>
endobj

5 0 obj
    <<
        /Type /Font 
        /Subtype /TrueType
        /Name /Fnt1
        /BaseFont /TimesNewRoman
        /Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding
    >>
endobj

6 0 obj
    <<
        /Type /Font 
        /Subtype /TrueType
        /Name /Fnt2
        /BaseFont /Helvetica
        /Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding
    >>
endobj

7 0 obj
    <<
        /Type /Page
        /Parent 3 0 R
        /Contents 8 0 R
        /MediaBox [0 0 612 792]
        /CropBox [0 0 612 792]
        /Resources
            <<
                /ExtGState
                    <<
                        /GS  <</ca 1    /CA 1    >>
                        /GS0 <</ca 0    /CA 0    >>
                        /GS1 <</ca 0.25 /CA 0.25 >>
                        /GS2 <</ca 0.5  /CA 0.5  >>
                        /GS3 <</ca 0.75 /CA 0.75 >>
                        /GS4 <</ca 1    /CA 1    >>
                    >>
                /Font
                    <<
                        /Fnt1 5 0 R 
                        /Fnt2 6 0 R 
                    >>
            >>
    >>
endobj

8 0 obj
    << /Length 9 0 R >>
stream
    
    BT
        /Fnt1 23.04 Tf
        284.239 738.72 Td
        (R) Tj
    ET
 
    BT
        /Fnt1 8.64 Tf
        303.84 36 Td
        (Page 1) Tj
    ET

    %----------------------------------------------
    
    % set clipping rect
    W
    54.72 684.72 501.93 71.28 re
    n

    % transform graphics
    1 0 0 1 -2921.22 583.74 cm   % translate into clipping rect
    0.72 0 0 0.72 0 0  cm        % scale GDI+ to PDF
    1 0 0 -1 0 0  cm             % mirror about X-axis
    1 0 0 1 0 -380.1875 cm       % translate mirrored image into clipping rect
 
    % adjust graphic state
    0 G
    0.5 w

    % draw and stroke 5 lines (these will be shifted and clipped in the clipping rect)
    0 173.938 m
    60060 173.938 l
    S
    0 182.188 m
    60060 182.188 l
    S
    0 190.438 m
    60060 190.438 l
    S
    0 198.688 m
    60060 198.688 l
    S
    0 206.938 m
    60060 206.938 l
    S

    %---------------------------------------------- 

endstream
endobj

9 0 obj
    12357
endobj

10 0 obj
    <<
        /Type /Page
        /Parent 3 0 R
        /Contents 11 0 R
        /MediaBox [0 0 612 792]
        /CropBox [0 0 612 792]
        /Resources
            <<
                /ExtGState
                    <<
                        /GS  <</ca 1    /CA 1    >>
                        /GS0 <</ca 0    /CA 0    >>
                        /GS1 <</ca 0.25 /CA 0.25 >>
                        /GS2 <</ca 0.5  /CA 0.5  >>
                        /GS3 <</ca 0.75 /CA 0.75 >>
                        /GS4 <</ca 1    /CA 1    >>
                    >>
                /Font
                    <<
                        /Fnt1 5 0 R 
                        /Fnt2 6 0 R 
                    >>
            >>
    >>
endobj

11 0 obj
    << /Length 12 0 R >>
stream
    
    BT
        /Fnt2 23.04 Tf
        284.239 738.72 Td
        (R) Tj
    ET

    BT
        /Fnt2 8.64 Tf
        303.84 36 Td
        (Page 2) Tj
    ET

    %----------------------------------------------
    
    % set clipping rect
    W
    54.72 684.72 501.93 71.28 re
    n

    % transform graphics
    1 0 0 1 -2921.22 583.74 cm   % translate into clipping rect
    0.72 0 0 0.72 0 0  cm        % scale GDI+ to PDF
    1 0 0 -1 0 0  cm             % mirror about X-axis
    1 0 0 1 0 -380.1875 cm       % translate mirrored image into clipping rect
 
    % adjust graphic state
    0 G
    0.5 w

    % draw and stroke 5 lines (these will be shifted and clipped in the clipping rect)
    0 173.938 m
    60060 173.938 l
    S
    0 182.188 m
    60060 182.188 l
    S
    0 190.438 m
    60060 190.438 l
    S
    0 198.688 m
    60060 198.688 l
    S
    0 206.938 m
    60060 206.938 l
    S

    %----------------------------------------------  
 
endstream
endobj

12 0 obj
    9177
endobj

4 0 obj
    <<
        /Font
            <<
                /Fnt1 5 0 R 
                /Fnt2 6 0 R 
            >>
        /ProcSet [/PDF /Text ]
    >>
endobj

3 0 obj
    <<
        /Type /Pages
        /Count 2
        /MediaBox [0 0 612 792]
        /CropBox [0 0 612 792]
        /Rotate 0
        /Kids [7 0 R 10 0 R  ]
        /Resources 4 0 R
    >>
endobj

xref
0 13
0000000000 65536 f 
0000000016 00000 n 
0000000138 00000 n 
0000000377 00000 n 
0000000536 00000 n 
0000000632 00000 n 
0000000759 00000 n 
0000000882 00000 n 
0000001424 00000 n 
0000002889 00000 n 
0000002911 00000 n 
0000003455 00000 n 
0000004920 00000 n 

trailer
<<
    /Size 13
    /Info 1 0 R
    /Root 2 0 R
>>
startxref
55407
%%EOF
```

Comment: There are quite a number of errors in your content stream, e.g. **W**, **n**, or **f** operations without a previously defined path. This might be unrelated to the issue itself but you really should fix these errors. Also the cross references are completely broken.

Comment: Another issue: the content stream **Length** values are completely off.

Comment: OK thanks ---- I will try to correct these issues ---- it will be hard as I am working in notepad

Comment: OK thanks ---- Although I can see I have lots of errors that need correcting, the issue here is **Bluebeam Revu** not being able to handle the setting of **clipping paths**, or **scaling** and **translation** the same way that **Acrobat** does ---- will this render properly in **SumatraPDF** if you copy/paste code? ---- there should be an **R** at top of page, **Page 1** at bottom of page, and **5 horizontal lines** drawn across the top of page (with about a 3/4" margin at left and right sides)

Comment: Please do yourself the favor and correct all the errors in your content streams before claiming some viewers cannot handle certain PDF features. With so many errors in those streams it essentially is pure luck if some viewers interpret them as you want...

Comment: I will work on making all corrections tonight

Comment: I fixed all the errors you pointed out, and incorporated @K L fixes as well ---- I've added the fixed file in the original question ---- Bluebeam now renders the 5 lines, but they are **not clipped** ---- I would like to know what the offending instructions actually was that was causing the lines to not render

Comment: You do `W    54.72 684.72 501.93 71.28 re    n` - that is incorrect, you first have to define the path _before_ you can use it as clip path. Thus, first the **re** operation, then **W**.

Comment: That works!!!!! ---- Bluebeam now renders as I was expecting---- Thank you! ---- Perhaps @K J can confirm that SumatraPdDF and the other viewer he tested both work ----- It seems Acrobat is much more forgiving with syntax errors

Comment: Out of interest, though - If you're creating the PDF manually in notepad, why do you use such a complicated way to achieve what you want? Why don't you simply draw 5 lines of the correct length right where you need them, why do you do all those transformations and clipping of much too long lines at the wrong coordinates?

Comment: The code  comes from an my app that draws graphics using GDI+ to screen & printer.  ---- All graphics is drawn full size in a long continuous strip, and then scaled, clipped, and translated down each page. ---- Pdf creation is also handled by my app, using my ugly code that seems to work good enough with Acrobat. ---- xref addresses seem to be OK when I create a file through my app, as Acrobat never nags to resave file. ---- I have to perform the extra step of mirroring only for the pdf because everything was drawing upside down ---- Only using notepad to create  minimal files to present here.

Answer (score 1):

Rather that me rewrite all of your basic corrections (to run in most readers) without fail, you should have noted that Acrobat will insist on "fixing" your file but in a way that you cannot see how the changes were needed.

I use MS Notepad to write such files, and it is a common failing to miscalculate offsets needed to avoid "fixing" by readers. You need to monitor Xref table with a hex editor set to decimal addressing mode.

The order of an Xref can be random and even highly variable but it's best while testing you keep objects in numeric order and thus the index table for your text could look something like this:

```
xref
0 13
0000000000 65536 f 
0000000016 00000 n 
0000000138 00000 n 
0000000377 00000 n 
0000000536 00000 n 
0000000632 00000 n 
0000000759 00000 n 
0000000882 00000 n 
0000001424 00000 n 
0000002889 00000 n 
0000002911 00000 n 
0000003455 00000 n 
0000004920 00000 n 

trailer
```

So without going through your file, line by line If I run `mutool clean -D -d input.pdf output.pdf` it will rationalise all your lengths and correct the order as above.

> The clean command pretty prints and rewrites the syntax of a PDF file. It can be used to repair broken files, expand compressed streams, filter out a range of pages, etc.

https://mupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mutool-clean.html

Thus unlike Acrobat you can compare the reordered text and use that for other comparative corrections.

[image]

So whilst that does not explain where corrections need to be made (@mkl has explained where syntax /structure is wrong) it will stop Acrobat fixing the files in an unhelpful way. The bonus is the if you keep that order as much as possible when making changes you can use a viewer that allows refreshing content whilst saving the text file. This is workwise similar to recompiling in LaTeX editors where you pre-view each change.

When acrobat fixes the file it seems many readers do not show the same result here the crop boundary is non functioning:

[image]

So this does not say why Acrobat works and others don't, I simply remove the many different entries area before the lines, and simplify to add a cutting block when another editor has replaced that boundary. per @mkl 's comment:

> errors in your content stream, e.g. W, n, or f operations without a previously defined path.

However I will need to re build XREF with mutool (after a few edits and save) but it works well in other viewers.

```
54.72 684.72 m
556.65 684.72 l
556.65 756 l
54.72 756 l
h W n
```

[image]

And here is above clip as shown in BB Revu V last 32 bit version 20.3

[image]

Comment: Thanks @K J ---- I will use your fixed xref ---- Your screenshot answers my question if SumatraPDF would render this file correctly ---- It does not ---- So my question is Why does Acrobat render differently than other viewers?

Comment: With Bluebeam, not only the Clipping Rectangle is not working, the transformations functions are also not working, as the 5 lines don't even draw at all.

Comment: With the revised code now posted, **Bluebeam now renders the 5 lines** as your one clip shows, but **unclipped** still

Comment: Thank you @K J ---- All seems good now with regards to rendering the 5 lines in the Clipping Rectangle in both Acrobat and Bluebeam ---- 2 other differences between the two I am noticing ---- 1. In Acrobat the lines are always crisp black 1 pixel wide, 2 pixel wide, etc depending on zoom, in Bluebeam they are anti-aliased with shades of gray/black ----Why the difference? ---- 2. The "R" on page 2 is Helvetica; in Acrobat it renders as Arial, in Bluebeam it renders as Helvetica ---- Why the difference?

Comment: OK thanks @K J :)

Answer (score 1):

A couple of notes on how to debug.

You can check/fix the overall structure of your file by running it through cpdf or qpdf:

`cpdf in.pdf -o out.pdf`

`qpdf in.pdf out.pdf`

You can also check the content stream is syntactically correct by trying to get cpdf to add text:

`cpdf out.pdf -add-text foo -o out2.pdf`

Another way is to run it through GhostScript, which is generally pretty good at error reporting (including on page content).

In the case of your file, this works fine - so the content stream parses ok. It looks like a question of the semantics of the stream, as others have pointed out.

Comment: Thank you! ---- I actually started to look into GhostScript just the other day